# Set Deny on PutObject for only existing files in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to prevent users to overwrite (or upload a new version of) a file in a s3 bucket. For that I'm thinking to set a Deny on PutObject on only existing files but allow creating new files in the bucket.

If it can be done with a conditional Deny policy what would be the condition?

Please let me know if there are any other ways.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/list_amazons3.html there are conditions to limit commands by existing tag but not for `PutObject`

Comment: No simple way to do this afaik. One [option](https://dev.to/goceb/preventing-object-replacement-in-amazon-s3-46d0) is to enable versioning and then add some S3 event-triggered automation to detect the upload of version 2+ of a given object or the deletion of an object and then automatically revert those actions by removing all versions of the object except v1 and removing all delete markers.

Answer (score 0):

I think s3 file locking is what you need: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lock.html combining it with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-s3-batch.html

Idea is that if a new version is created and does not contain a file lock, you immediately delete it.